# Will switching Ubuntu clocksource from xen to tsc impact php/Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, newrelic, xen

## Background

We started using new relic on our laravel app server (hosted on ubuntu ec2) but then immediately noticed a jump in latency in our aws cloudwatch: 
[image]

New relic tech support immediately suggested that we switch our clock source from xen to tsc:

> It appears that the clocksource on your system isn't supporting vDSO.
>   Since the PHP Agent heavily relies on the gettimeofday() system call
>   to determine the length of time of segments and transactions,
>   clocksource plays a big role in preventing system calls from hitting
>   the system itself which greatly speeds things up.
>
> In this particular scenario we recommend using the tsc clocksource. We
>   have seen big performance gains with tsc clocksource enabled and I
>   wanted to ask if it would be possible for you to temporarily enable
>   the tsc clocksource to see if the overhead reduces.
>
> If New Relic is the only application for which accurate timing is
>   required, or if you're only concerned with accurately measuring
>   shorter durations, tsc is a good choice for clocksource.

I did a quick [search](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/timekeeping-linux-vms) on the difference between the two clocksources, and didn't find any giant red flags (there were these issues that were mentioned here:
TSC, however, has its own issues, including:

> - Its frequency is unknown, and it needs to be measured with PIT, CMOS,
>     or ACPI timer.
> - The register is writable and the reading can differ on
>     different CPUs.
> - TSC can stop in some low-power C states of the
>     processor. This doesn't usually happen on modern hardware.
> - TSC getting
>     out-of-sync on some big NUMA systems was observed in the past.
>     Luckily, the number of such systems was limited.
> - SMI handlers may reset the counter.

All of this sounds foreign to me, but it seems that they are only relevant for micro- time keeping needs (such as profilers etc) and I don't think its' really relevant for a php/laravel app where we can tolerate inaccuracy in time with a threshold up to 3 seconds (but not more, as our application relies on real time notifications to users).

Am I right with my assumption?

## appendix I: instructions from new relic support team on how to switch from xen to tsc:

> To set the current clock source to a different value
>
> Run bash as a super user to override the current_clocksource:
>
> sudo bash -c 'echo tsc >
>   /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource' Run
>   the dmesg command to view the kernel messages:
>
> dmesg | less If the override was successful, the following message
>   appears:
>
> clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc

Answer (score 1):

I made a lot of research on this topic this week. My stack is quite similar to yours, the only difference is that I'm running on an ECS Optimized AMI.

If your application doesn't need mile-seconds precision, it should be okay for you to switch to TSC. Make sure that you are running on a new generation, with an updated kernel. This is the impact that I saw, with basically half of the instances: https://i.stack.imgur.com/guHZw.jpg

AWS recommended to use their own service to keep time in sync: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/

I'm still organizing my references, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: _Make sure that you are running on a new generation, with an updated kernel. This is the impact that I saw, with basically half of the instances_ I got a couple of questions 1. a new generation of _what_? 2. what caused this drop in latency.. was it switching from xen to tsc?

Comment: Generation is how AWS calls the version of their instances.
Family is type of instance.

For example: an M4.large instance, belongs to the M Family, Generation 4 with size large.

More about it here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html

About TSC, it is recommended to have at least the fourth generation. And Yes, the drop was because of the change of the clocksource from xen to tsc

Comment: _About TSC, it is recommended to have at least the fourth generation._.. that's extremely interesting, can you you please provide me a reference for that?

Comment: Also a sanity check question: the graph you showed above is with ec2 instances using new relic right? or are you talking in general?

Comment: mmm i just realized that my instances are running m4.xlarge instances.. which should still be more than enough.. i'm still getting those latencies.. bummer!

Comment: Check the current clocksource for your instances, remember that if you need to restart the instance you need to approach it by changing on the grub settings for the kernel.

Comment: not sure what you mean by the grub settings.. see appendix I in my question, contains exact details on how to change the settings

Comment: If you restart the instance that is lost